# Can I put a <section> inside a <header>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have not been able to find a reference describing the relationship between the HTML5 tags `header` and `section` (or `footer` and `section`). Most examples put `p` elements inside headers and footers.

Is it both legal and advisable to put a `section` element into a header?

References:

- [The main element](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/) - you may not put a `main` element into an `article`
- "Nesting <article> in <section> or Vice Versa?" in [HTML5 semantic elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) - putting an `article` into a `section` is valid, and the other way round (although different semantics)

Comment: I don't think it matters if you put a section within a header, but the other way around may not work as well (keep header/footer as the parent element). Also I've found that div elements do not work within sections but sections within div have not posed problems in my experience. Here's a small fiddle for your header https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/m5dfL8gL/

Comment: Side note regarding the last reference (nesting `article` in `section` or vice-versa): That’s wrong advice. It *does* matter, the cases are semantically different.

Comment: @unor updated my summary to reflect your comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.

Formally, the [content model of header elements](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-header-element) is

> Flow content, but with no header or footer element descendants.

And the [contexts in which section elements can be used](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-section-element) is

> Where sectioning content is expected.

[Sectioning content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#sectioning-content) is subset of [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2), so that means anywhere flow content is expected, except places where it's nevertheless explicitly called out as not allowed, which as we see above, it isn't for header.

(The places where it is currently called out as not allowed are as the descendants of an [`address`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-address-element:concept-element-content-model), [`dt`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element:concept-element-content-model), and [`th`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element:concept-element-content-model) element.)